# Running .msi package from Command line in Silent Mode isn't working in WINDOW 8?

Tags: command, windows-installer, installshield, silent

I have built an .msi package from InstallShield and name it "Dell Printer Hub.msi". I run it from Command Line in Window 7 as below:

```
D:\package>msiexec /i "Dell Printer Hub.msi" /qn
```

It's working in window 7. But when I run this Command Line in window 8, it's not working at all. I have tried "/qb", "/qr", "/qf" and they worked fine.

I also have tried "/quiet" but it's not worked in window 8.

How can i run .msi package from Command Line as silent mode in window 8. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `/l*v install.log` and the read the results to see why it isn't working.  Odds are UAC is enabled and you are invoking this from a standard user command prompt.  There could also be a design defect in the MSI that doesn't like Windows 8 and/or missing prereqs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will add this command and reply my result for you. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you launched the Command Prompt using the "Run as administrator" option?

Comment: No, I didn't launch the Command Prompt as administrator. I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in my answer above.